# Is there any relation between (a+b+c) and (abc)?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

If value of $a+b+c$ is given as $n$ and it is provided that a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup>. So, I need to find the value of $(abc)$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=9  @MarkBennet

Comment: I have already solved it and I am just curious about the direct relation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding a Pythagorean triple $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ with $a+b+c=40$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258204/finding-a-pythagorean-triple-a2-b2-c2-with-abc-40)

Comment: But have you tried squaring $a+b+c=n$ and eliminating $a^2+b^2$ and $a+b$? Or anything simple like that, to make progress.

Comment: If you've already solved it, show us; we can't read minds.

Comment: @Shaun By that I mean, I have solved Project Euler problem #9 by finding individual values of a, b and c. Do I need to show you my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hope for an answer in general, because two equations in three variables will generally give a one dimensional set of points. But the answer can sometimes be given in terms of a single parameter. Here it is easy enough to work through:

$$a+b+c=n$$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2c(a+b)+2ab=n^2$$

$$2c^2+2c(n-c)+2ab=n^2$$

$$2cn+2ab=n^2$$

$$2c^2n+2abc=cn^2$$

$$abc=\frac{cn(n-2c)}2$$

Comment: Note that $2c\lt n$ is simply the triangle inequality.

Comment: I think the last line should be abc = cn(n - 2c)/2.

Answer (score 0):

the points $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2=z^2$ form an infinite cone in the $x,y,z$ plane.

The points $(x,y,z)$ with $x+y+z=\alpha$ form a plane. The intersection of the plane and the cone is a conic.

This conic can contain a large number of lattice points.